# Date Function in R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2

Have been having trouble running date_function on R. I have tried a couple of different examples. Steps to reproduce

#### Example 1

```
 coord_x_date(xlim = c("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09"), ylim = 
  c(5,30)) 
    +

   scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "2 hours")
   Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class 
 POSIXct only
```

#### Example 2

```
coord_x_date(xlim = c("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09"), ylim = c(5,30)) +

scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "2 hours")
Error in cut.Date(date, time, right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE) :
invalid specification of 'breaks'
```

#### Example 3

```
  coord_x_date(xlim = c("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09"), ylim = c(5,30)) +
+

    scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 day"), minor_breaks = 
    date_breaks("2 hour"))
      Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class 
    POSIXct only
```

scale_x_datetime(xlim =as.POSIXct( c("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09"))) does not work
Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You are using character string dates and it's asking for POSIXct. The error message is clear.

Comment: `scale_x_datetime(xlim =as.POSIXct( c("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09")))` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coord_x_datetime` to correspond `scale_x_datetime`

```
  coord_x_datetime(xlim = c(("2020-07-02", "2020-07-09"), ylim = c(5,30)) +
 scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "1 hours")
```